# Symfony 6 Dockerfile : Could not open input file: ./bin/console

Tags: php, docker, symfony, dockerfile, composer-php

it's my first time using Docker in a project (a Symfony project). In this project i don't have any database, i just want to have the PHP version (8.3.1) and the projects dependencies.

This is the error i get when i do docker compose up --build :

### 1.025 Executing script cache:clear [KO]
1.031  [KO]
1.031 Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
1.031 !!  Could not open input file: ./bin/console
1.031 !!
1.031 Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c composer install --no-dev --no-interaction" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM composer:lts as deps

WORKDIR /app

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=composer.json,target=composer.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=composer.lock,target=composer.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/cache \
    composer install --no-dev --no-interaction

FROM php:8.3.1-apache as final

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY --from=deps app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor

COPY src /var/www/html

USER www-data
```

This is my compose.yml file :

services:
server:
build:
context: .
ports:
- 9000:80

I tried to find a solution online but i found nothing recent related to Symfony with Docker

Comment: Please check the formatting of your Q, the big and bold part doesn't look right. That said, `USER  www-data` surely didn't cause this error message, so this is not a [mcve]. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does `bin/console` exist?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that you are running *composer install* before copying your src folder to /var/www/html.

I would suggest to

1. start with the base PHP image
2. move the src folder
3. install composer
4. run composer install.

In your case it will be something like:

```
FROM php:8.3.1-apache

#Update and install php dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install nano zip unzip wget git locales locales-all libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev pkg-config libssl-dev -y && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Copy code
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY src .

# install composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# install project php dependencies
RUN composer install

# Other layers follow
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help carloliwanag, i had to add two lines to make it works.

This is my code right now :

```
FROM php:8.3.1-apache

#Update and install php dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install nano zip unzip wget git locales locales-all libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev pkg-config libssl-dev -y && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Copy code
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY src .

COPY composer.json .

# install composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# install project php dependencies
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

RUN composer install
```